# How to speedup delete from table with multiple references

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, transactions, sql-server-2014

I have a table which depends on several other ones.

When I delete an entry in this table I should also delete entries in its "masters" (it's 1-1 relation). But here is a problem: when I delete it I get unnecessary table scans, because it checks a reference before deleting. I am sure that it's safe (becuase I get ids from OUTPUT clause):

```
DELETE TOP (@BatchSize) [doc].[Document]
OUTPUT DELETED.A, DELETED.B, DELETED.C, DELETED.D
INTO @DocumentParts
WHERE Id IN (SELECT d.Id FROM @DocumentIds d); 

SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;    

DELETE [doc].[A]
WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT dp.A FROM @DocumentParts dp); 

DELETE [doc].[B]
WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT dp.B FROM @DocumentParts dp); 

DELETE [doc].[C]
WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT dp.C FROM @DocumentParts dp); 

... several others
```

But here is what plan I get for each delete:
[image]

If I drop constraints from `document` table plan changes:
[image]

But problem is that I cannot drop constraints because inserts perform in parallel in other sessions. I also cannot lock a whole table becuase it's very large, and this lock will also lock a lot of others transactions.

The only way I found for now is create an index for every foreign key (which can be used instead of PK scan), but I wanted to avoid this scan at all (indexed or not), becuase I am SURE that documents with such ids doesn't exists becuase I used to delete them. Maybe there is some hint for SQL or some way to disable a reference check for one transaction insead of whole database.

Comment: Also try to replace `IN..DISTINCT` with `EXISTS`.

Comment: That first delete does not look very efficient to me.  Are you not having performance problems with it?

Comment: To me is not necessarily safe.  You are very likely to have more of the same value A,B,D,C  in a future batch.  Are you getting no FK violations with the check?

Comment: @Paparazzi, I wrote in question that it's 1-1 relation. Globally, it's a single table, which is just splitted in several for complexity minimization reasons. And no, I don't have any problems with first delete.

Comment: That statement is bit conflicted to me "When I delete an entry in this table I should also delete entries in its "masters" (it's 1-1 relation)."    EntrieS.  Unless you have a unique constraint on all those then it is a 1-1 that is not enforced and there would be no  cause for the select distinct.  You have what you need.  I cannot be of value.  To me they question is inconsistent.

Comment: @Paparazzi entrie`s` because for example we have tables A, B, C and D. which is one entity with fields A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*. When we starting delete from `A`, we need also delete entrieS in B, C and D, for one in each table.

Comment: its "masters" is already plural.  "entries in its "masters"" is mulitple entries in each to me.  And again if it is unique then what is the purpose of the distinct?

Comment: @Paparazzi it's not very useful to have one table with 50+ columns. For example, document has storage info (size, language, ...), but it's not relevant to its content. Thus storage is in `StorageInfo` table, when general document table is in `Document`. The same way as you don't have a class with 100500 properties, but you split it on several parts, and it is commonly a 1-1 relation.

Comment: It is an inconsistent problem statement and you are having performance issues so just possibly it is not the best design.   And for the 3rd time if what is say is true there is not purpose to the distinct.  And if there is not a unique then 1:1 is not even enforced.   50+ columns is useful if that is actual data relationship and it is performant.   100500 properties?  No real object has that many related properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116603/discussion-between-alex-zhukovskiy-and-paparazzi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is rather stubborn in preserving the referential integrity, so no, you cannot "hint" to disable the check. The fact that you deleted the referencing rows doesn't matter at all (in a high transactional environment, there was plenty of time for some process to modify the tables between the deletes).

Creating the proper indexes is the way to go.